# how to capture email address or name through an email sent

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, email

If I send an email to someone, and at the bottom of the email is a link.

Lets say the link is, `click me`.

When user clicks on this link he is taken to a webpage.

This webpage will show `"Thank you"` and webpage will name will be say `thanks.php`

How can I show the name (or email) of the person who clicked this link, in his email on this webpage?

i.e. when he clicks the link in the email, and is taken to the webpage `thanks.php`, how can he see the message:

> "Thank you Amit Gupta"

or

> "Thank you amit00000000@fmail.com"

while Amit Gupta and/or amit00000000@fmail.com shall be taken from the email in which he clicked on this link.

I will be grateful if you provide the answer of this question.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You store his email address in the session or in a database on the server in a relation to an uid given as parameter or you give the email as parameter

Comment: @ReeCube — You could use a session, but that would be a stupid idea. There's a very good change that the session will have ended before the link is followed … or that the link will be opened in a different browser.

Comment: Yes i relized it too, sorry

Comment: @ReeCube spelling of "realized" is wrong :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try something like this, but you have to complement it to your needs.

**register.php:** *(or whatever)*

```
<?php
$id = uniqid();
$link = 'linktoyourfile/thanks.php?id=' . $id;

// TODO: save $id in a database in relation with the email of your user
//        and then send the $link variable to the given email address.

/*
   //Something like this:

   $subject = 'Subject';
   $message = '<a href="'.$link.'">Click here to activate or what ever</a>';
   $header  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
   $header .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
   $header .= 'To: ' . 'His Name <' . $mail . '>' . "\r\n";
   $header .= 'From: Your Name <your@email.com>' . "\r\n";
   mail($mail, $subject, $message, $header);
*/
?>
```

**thanks.php:**

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
   $id = $_GET['id'];
   // TODO: read the email from the database with the $id variable
   //        and set it to the $email variable
   echo 'Thank you '. $email;
}
?>
```

Comment: While you said send the $link variable to the given email address, so for each email i have to manually send different $id?

Comment: you can use the mail function in php: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Can you please tell me what shall be the link that is to be sent in email? Thanks

Comment: the link contains the url/path to the thanks.php file and the generated and stored id as GET parameter 'id'

Answer (score 3):

When you send the email:

- Generate a unique identifier
- Put it in the link (e.g. in the query string of the URL)
- Store it with the name in a database

When the link is clicked:

- Look up the id in the database
- Get the data you stored with it
- Output that data to the page

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. Can you please show how can it be done?

Comment: That would involve writing the whole thing for you, so no. If you have a specific problem with your implementation then you could ask a specific question about it.

Comment: You could put the email id instead of the identifier as he mentioned in the 2nd output.

Answer (score 0):

Before you send the email to the user from your system, you will maintain a tracking id of that mail in your database across the user, this tracking id could be

```
$tracking_id = md5($uid . time());
```

`$uid -> is the user_id`

And in the link you add this tracking_id as the query parameter, so when the user clicks the link, you can search for this tracking_id and lookup in database for the user this link was.

Example url: `http://abcd.com/thankyou.php?tracking_id=12352342345`

Then you can display the user details you want, also along with that you can capture the click details and consider this email as read email.

Comment: Directly place the user_id in the link as `thankyou.php?user_id=12` and show the user details on your thank you page by getting value from `$_GET['user_id']` and get this user from database

Answer (score -1):

On click of the link parse the email text to get the From Email and send it as a parameter to the GET request.

Comment: How can you parse the email text when the link is clicked? You can't run code in the user's email client.

Comment: @Quentin : I assumed he was reading the email on his own website.

Comment: The first sentence of the question is: "If I send an email to someone"